# tag__in does not return posts

Tags: theme-development, wp-query

I want to get a custom post type posts with the same tags. Here's what I'm trying:

```
$tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'item-tags' );    //returns tags array correctly

if ($tags) {

    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach($tags as $single_tag){
        $tag_ids[] = $single_tag->term_id;
    }

    $args = array(
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,  
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),                         
        'post_type' => 'item',                          
        'showposts' => 5,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );  

}
```

It does not return any post. If I remove tag_*in and post*_not_in then it returns all posts correctly. Is there anything wrong with the above arguments?

Comment: are 'item-tags' a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Re: my comment, I am assuming 'item_tags' are a custom taxonomy. `tag__in` only works for WP Core's Tag taxonomy. Replace your `tag__in` line with the following:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $tag_ids
        )
    )
```